# Eloquent next record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the last 3 blog post from the database into single variables (for templates). I saw a good implementation at some other thred and it works fine for the next record but on the third query returns with NULL. What is your opinion about this problem?

**BlogController.php:**

```
public function getIndex($l = 'hu')
    {
        $post_last = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        $post_2 = $post_last->next($post_last->created_at);
        $post_3 = $post_2->next($post_2->created_at);

        var_dump($post_3);
    }
```

**Post.php:(Model)**

```
<?php

namespace Civitas;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Physical table name
     */
    protected $table = 'posts';


    /**
     * Get next result in record list
     *
     * @param $created_at
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function next($c) {
        return Post::where('created_at', '<', $c)->get()->first();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell why your function doesn't work, but I suggest you try this approach:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
$post1 = $posts->shift();
$post2 = $posts->shift();
$post3 = $posts->shift();
```

This will only run one query instead of three. Calling `shift()` on the collection will then return the first item and remove it so the second post will be "first" the next time you call it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `next` function, the result will give the earliest post, not the next one. Therefore, the third call will return null because there is no post after the earliest one. Adding `orderBy` for `created_at` field, it will work as expected.

```
public function next(){
    return static::where('created_at', '<' , $this->created_at)
                    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                    ->first();
}
```

Then in your controller, you can call like this:

```
$post_last = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
$post2 = $post_last->next();
$post3 = post_last->next()->next();
```